# Azure Function - Powershell and Azure storage table (INSERT OR REPLACE)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-storage

I usually use node to write my function but this was required to be in powershell.

I'm trying to write data in the Azure storage Table, but if data exists it will not replace it with the following code:

```
Push-OutputBinding -Name outputTable -Value @{
                    PartitionKey = $PartitionKey
                    RowKey = $RowKey
                    Description = $description
        }
```

I've been looking everywhere (docs and google) but I cannot find the method to replace the content of a row if the row exists, basically I would like to perform the same insert of replace that I have in node.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hopefully, this is what you are looking for. It's an article on updating entities in Azure Storage Tables with Powershell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell#updating-entities, unfortunately, you'll have to find the row first and if it exists update it.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this and let you know

Comment: Hello Mike,I was able to use this to add or update the table rows, but I have an issue while using it in a foreach loop. Although I have a Write-host that prints the data before pushing to the table (that shows correct data) , when I go to check the table the data is misplaced, A has the data of B , B of C and C is empty, do you know why it's happening?

Comment: Hi Mike, I was able to fix it, thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/table-storage-how-to-use-powershell#updating-entities suggested by Mike in my post comment!

Works in foreach loop, be carefull if you use regex for match.

Answer (score 1):

According to your need, your can use [`Insert Or Merge`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/insert-or-merge-entity) operation. The operation will update an existing entity or inserts a new entity if it does not exist in the table. Regarding how to do that in Azure function with powershell, please refer to the following steps

1. Install module

Please add a 'Az' = '5.*' keypair to the requirements.psd1

2. Script

```
import-module Az.Storage

$e = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity("Jim","test")
$pro= New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.EntityProperty("test")
$pros = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.EntityProperty]'
$pros.add("Description",$pro)
$e.Properties=$pros

$aaccountName="andyprivate"
$accountkey="h4pP1fe****U8CacyVMlTWAUA5A=="
$tableName="test"

$ctx =New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $aaccountName  -StorageAccountKey $accountkey
$table=Get-AzStorageTable -Name $tableName   -Context $ctx
[Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableOperation]$tableOperation=[Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableOperation]::InsertOrMerge($e)
$table.CloudTable.Execute($tableOperation)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jim, thank you for the suggestion, this will work with Azure table storage as well? I read a lot of Azure Cosmo references, It might be working only for that product?

Comment: @Ostage It is also work for Azure table storage.